# Mongo doesn't accept insertion of duplicate usernames

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I need mongo to accept duplicate usernames because it is possible that you might have the same username for a different site, I have my code like this.

```
_(data)
    .forEach(function (a, key) {
        jobs['insert_' + a] = function (callback) {
          mongo.open(config.MONGO_DB)
            .collection('usernames')
            .insert({
               username: a,
               indic: key,
               favorites: ''
             }, function (err, result) {
                  if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                  }

                  callback();
            });
       };
     }
  .commit();
async.parallel(jobs, send_response);
```

and I only get this one line as a result

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5592724901c01a6ca6b76a6a"), "username" : "asd", "indic" : "twitch", "favorites" : "" }
```

and the data I am passing is:

```
data = {twitch: 'asd', hitbox: 'asd', dailymotion: 'asd'}
```

Shouldn't I have something like this?

```
`{ "_id" : ObjectId("5592724901c01a6ca6b76axx"), "username" : "asd", "indic" : "twitch", "favorites" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5592724901c01a6ca6b76axx"), "username" : "asd", "hitbox" : "twitch", "favorites" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5592724901c01a6ca6b76axx"), "username" : "asd", "dailymotion" : "twitch", "favorites" : "" }
```

I am using [this](https://github.com/caolan/async) as my `async` function.

Comment: `unique` option in http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#db.collection.createIndex ? Just a wild guess, not familiar with mongodb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `a` variable is the one that is duplicated, so you keep adding the same key to `jobs` (namely `insert_asd`).

If you don't necessarily need to refer to the specific insert actions in the results, you can make `jobs` an array instead of an object:

```
var jobs = _(data).map(function(a, key) {
  return function(callback) {
    ....
  };
}).value();
```

However, it may be possible with your MongoDB driver to add the documents in one go, instead of separately. The official MongoDB driver supports arrays of documents using [`insertMany()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#insertMany), for instance.

Comment: wow jeez didn't see that. i just changed it to the `key` and it now works. thanks!